# devise forgot password function not working when creating own user controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I use devise for authentication and i have created a user controller and specified as shown below in my routes which lets me to create users,edit and delete users,

```
devise_for :users do
resources :users, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end
```

but i cannot able to make the forgot password functionality work using this but in case i  specify as

```
devise_for :users
```

then i can able to use the forgot password function that comes with devise and i could not able to create , edit or delete when i specify like this. So how can i make both to work ? 
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got the way that i was looking and this is it...

```
devise_for :users do
      resources :users, :only => [:create]
      end
    devise_scope :user do
      resources :users, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

change your route for users, see this

1. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
2. http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

route like - for example

```
devise_for :users, :path => "usuarios", :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret', :confirmation => 'verification', :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'register', :sign_up => 'cmon_let_me_in' }
```

Comment: i cannot understand what it will do. As of my understanding it just creates alternative names for the default names, but how would it solve my issue?

Comment: did you see that video 209-introducing-devise ?

Comment: see video and step by step follow that step given in video

Comment: i saw that video and it just shows how to use devise and i am asking for using separate users controller which should be used to create a new user but at the same time i want the devise/passwords#new, devise/passwords#edit paths also work. how can i do this?